# angularjs ng-pattern change css style of elements based on regex condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-pattern

In my angularjs form, I am checking the password pattern with a regex that checks for multiple conditions. Based on different condition checks of this regex, I want to change the css for one of the elements.

**[Jsfiddle link Here .](http://jsfiddle.net/2G8gA/671/)**

***The source model that inspired this is from [here](https://sso.godaddy.com/v1/account/create).***

This is my function to check the pattern against the regex :

```
$scope.passPatternCheck= (function() {
    var regexp = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#\$%&'\(\)\*\+,\-\.\/:;\<=\>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}~]?)[A-Za-z\d!#\$%&'\(\)\*\+,\-\.\/:;\<=\>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}~]{8,}/;
    return {
        test: function(value) {               
            return regexp.test(value);
        }
    };
})();
```

### Some notes:

- this regex don't check for the starting/ending spaces; this should also be adjusted
- the `ng-if` that shows/hides the div of the conditions list is not currently working.

### question:

I want to reproduce the same behaviour from the godaddy site account creation page. So the goal is to have the same css behaviour according to the condition completed.
[image]

### update 2:

my submit button of the form `theForm` should get disabled if any of the fields that are required are not filled out or an error in the patterns occurred:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"ng-disabled="theForm.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">
</button>
```

but with the [Shantanu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45622020/8041860), this is not yet possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding one regex for `ng-pattern` will not achieve it. Because if regex test fails then we would not know exactly which case of all those checkbox conditions failed. You've to handle different regex for each conditions & check them in either custom directives (using `$validators`) and create custom validators for that each validation **OR** you can check those condition on change of password input field inside controller & create one object with different properties as Boolean values for those validation conditions.

I've created jsfiddle for 2nd method: http://jsfiddle.net/shantanu_k/Lnupw3p2/7/

Updated based on updated question (form has to be invalid if any conditions fail & thus making submit button disabled): http://jsfiddle.net/shantanu_k/Lnupw3p2/10/

Comment: really cool answer, but what about the password field being red when the conditions are not satisfied

Comment: cool, but there is a small bug, when you fulfill every condition, and then clear the password field, the length condition is checked! whereas it is empty.

Comment: @NarenMurali Have ng-class on input field & handle has-error based on those condition properties boolean values. Check this version: http://jsfiddle.net/shantanu_k/Lnupw3p2/9/

Comment: @Shantanu yeah it looks better, maybe a bit more css tweaks :)

Comment: why does it check the small letter by default in my dev environment?

Comment: No it doesn't. I've updated template, css, angular code.. make sure you're replicating just like that in your dev environment. http://jsfiddle.net/shantanu_k/Lnupw3p2/7/ version should fulfill all your required conditions

Comment: thanks its fine. But my project form submit button should be disabled until the password field is correctly filled out. currently it is not so. please see the update. thanks

Comment: @Bonnard Check my updated answer. Handle validity of such input manually using $setValidity.